# Angularjs modal windows dynamically (programmatically) built

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to implement a modal window whose contents is generated by the JavaScript controller (the contents is a hierarchical tree of accordions/panels whose structure is unknown till data is received).

The contents of the modal is defined in a view that includes ng-bind-html directive.

When displaying this just as a normal page (i.e. not as a modal) I get the contents and behavior matching the needs.

My problem is that I can't find the way to make it work as a modal.

Is there any limitation to Angular that I'm unaware of?

The same problem I have with another modal that is also in a view, but its contents is built using ng-repeat directive. In this second case, when I try to deploy data into fields, I get an error stating that the element I'm trying to set its value is undefined. It would appear that such attempt is taking place too early and the DOM is still not ready.

This second case also is not working when attempting to use it in a modal.

Comment: no there is no limitation, how did you try? Please provide some code to be able to help you.

Comment: Well, I tried several methods picked from examples. None of them worked. It may be important to add that I'm using a route provider from Angular. Tried including the page there, and getting the contents as a "page/view" and not as a modal. I'm not sure if the problem is the page or me not knowing good enough how to create a modal (though, as stated, followed the examples strictly).

Comment: just show me an example how did you try to solve it and I'll try to make it work

Comment: Cannot share the code since it is a lot and includes proprietary info (yes, I know... but I cannot do it right now). What  I can provide is a description of the method I'm using for the first case. I have a recursive function that creates elements like: `<div class="panel panel-default" id="Pannel_i"> <div class="panel-heading" id="collapse_Header_i"> [some additional contents] <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse_i"><div class="panel-body" id="collapse_Body_i">...` ("i" is a number). Then, I use `$scope.Mdl = $sce.trustAsHtml(HTML_String)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie with the models that you are using in the modal.  You may want to make sure the correct models are even being used.  The scope may not be the same in the modal window as it is as a pure template.  I like to test which scope things are truly in by using the ng-init or ng-if directives, and creating a function to see if it even gets called. So for example:

**HTML template**

```
<div class="panel" ng-if="scopeCheck">
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.scopeCheck = function() {
    debugger;  //or console.log('here');
}
```

If that is not the issue, then I'm not sure if you are creating this modal yourself, but if you are I would suggest maybe using the modal directive from [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and seeing if it works with that.

Comment: I have some additional modals to implement (e.g. error messages, etc.). Will use your suggestion and post the result here. Thanks for your suggestion.